# How to group by in base R

Tags: r, group-by

I would like to express the following SQL query using **base R** (without any particular package):

```
select month, day, count(*) as count, avg(dep_delay) as avg_delay
from flights
group by month, day
having count > 1000
```

It selects the mean departure delay and the number of flights per day on busy days (days with more than 1000 flights). The dataset is [nycflights13](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nycflights13/index.html) containing information of flights departed from NYC in 2013.

Notice I can easily write this in dplyr as:

```
flights %>%
  group_by(month, day) %>%
  summarise(count = n(), avg_delay = mean(dep_delay, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  filter(count > 1000)
```

Comment: Honestly, may I suggest that you just use `sqldf`?  You've already invested the time to write the query.

Comment: Well sqldf is not base, so harder to export code, not good practice for packages, and knowing base is good in general.

Comment: I think something like this should work: `subset(aggregate(dep_delay ~ month + day, flights, function(x) data.frame(count=length(x), avg_delay=mean(x,na.rm=TRUE))), count>1000)`

Answer (score 12):

Since I was reminded earlier about the elegance of `by` (tip of the hat to @Parfait), here is a solution using `by`:

```
res <- by(flights, list(flights$month, flights$day), function(x)
    if (nrow(x) > 1000) {
        c(
            month = unique(x$month),
            day = unique(x$day),
            count = nrow(x),
            avg_delay = mean(x$dep_delay, na.rm = TRUE))
        })

# Store in data.frame and order by month, day
df <- do.call(rbind, res);
df <- df[order(df[, 1], df[, 2]) ,];
#     month day count avg_delay
#[1,]     7   8  1004 37.296646
#[2,]     7   9  1001 30.711499
#[3,]     7  10  1004 52.860702
#[4,]     7  11  1006 23.609392
#[5,]     7  12  1002 25.096154
#[6,]     7  17  1001 13.670707
#[7,]     7  18  1003 20.626789
#[8,]     7  25  1003 19.674134
#[9,]     7  31  1001  6.280843
#[10,]     8   7  1001  8.680402
#[11,]     8   8  1001 43.349947
#[12,]     8  12  1001  8.308157
#[13,]    11  27  1014 16.697651
#[14,]    12   2  1004  9.021978
```

Comment: `by` is a great Base R function. My only gripe is that the value, an object of class `by`, is pretty underdeveloped (and not all that necessary). I find it useful to define a method for `as.data.frame.by` which does as you show here.

Comment: I do agree with you @AdamO; but in all fairness (to `by`:-), the return object of `by` is just a `list` with some additional `attributes`.

Answer (score 4):

as commented you can use a combi of `subset` and `aggregate`. Changed the order of day & month to recieve the same order as your `dplyr` approach. Using `na.action = NULL` to count rows inclunding `NA`s.

```r
library(nycflights13) 
#> Warning: Paket 'nycflights13' wurde unter R Version 3.4.4 erstellt
subset(aggregate(dep_delay ~ day + month, flights, 
       function(x) cbind(count=length(x), avg_delay=mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)),
       na.action = NULL), 
       dep_delay[,1] > 1000)
#>     day month dep_delay.1 dep_delay.2
#> 189   8     7 1004.000000   37.296646
#> 190   9     7 1001.000000   30.711499
#> 191  10     7 1004.000000   52.860702
#> 192  11     7 1006.000000   23.609392
#> 193  12     7 1002.000000   25.096154
#> 198  17     7 1001.000000   13.670707
#> 199  18     7 1003.000000   20.626789
#> 206  25     7 1003.000000   19.674134
#> 212  31     7 1001.000000    6.280843
#> 219   7     8 1001.000000    8.680402
#> 220   8     8 1001.000000   43.349947
#> 224  12     8 1001.000000    8.308157
#> 331  27    11 1014.000000   16.697651
#> 336   2    12 1004.000000    9.021978
```

Created on 2018-04-05 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 0):

Not a particularly elegant solution, but this will do what you want using Base R

```
flights_split <- split(flights, f = list(flights$month, flights$day))

result <- lapply(flights_split, function(x) {
  if(nrow(x) > 1000) {
    data.frame(month = unique(x$month), day = unique(x$day), avg_delay = mean(x$dep_delay, na.rm = T), count = nrow(x))
  } else {
    NULL
  }
}
)

do.call(rbind, result)

#        month day mean_delay    n
#  12.2     12   2   9.021978 1004
#  8.7       8   7   8.680402 1001
#  7.8       7   8  37.296646 1004
#  8.8       8   8  43.349947 1001
#  7.9       7   9  30.711499 1001
#  7.10      7  10  52.860702 1004
#  7.11      7  11  23.609392 1006
#  7.12      7  12  25.096154 1002
#  8.12      8  12   8.308157 1001
#  7.17      7  17  13.670707 1001
#  7.18      7  18  20.626789 1003
#  7.25      7  25  19.674134 1003
#  11.27    11  27  16.697651 1014
#  7.31      7  31   6.280843 1001
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
grp <- expand.grid(mth = unique(flights$month), d = unique(flights$day))
out <- mapply(function(mth, d){
    sub_data <- subset(flights, month == mth & day == d)
    df <- data.frame(
        month = mth,
        day = d,
        count = nrow(sub_data), 
        avg_delay = mean(sub_data$dep_delay, na.rm = TRUE)
    )
    df[df$count > 1000]
}, grp$mth, grp$d)
res <- do.call(rbind, out)
```

This is a lot slower than the `dplyr` solution.