# Subset data.frame based on lag between two columns

Tags: r

Suppose you want to subset a data.frame where the rule for keeping rows is based
on a lag beteen rows 'a' and 'b':

```
# input
df <- data.frame(a = c(1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                 b = c(0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1))

#output
  a b
1 1 0
2 0 1
3 0 1
4 1 0
5 0 1
6 0 1
```

Essentially, if `'a' = 1` you want to keep that row as well as the subsequent run of rows in
'b' that have a value of 1. This capture continues until the next row with `a = 0 & b = 0`.
I've tried using nested 'ifelse()' statements, but I am stuck incorporate logical tests based on a lag issue.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I would do it. There are probably options out there that require maybe 1 or 2 lines less.

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                 b = c(0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1))

library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(grp = cumsum(a==1|a+b==0)) %>%
  group_by(grp) %>%
  filter(any(a == 1)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(a, b)
```

Comment: Would `df %>% group_by(grp = cumsum(a == 1 | b == 0)) %>% filter(first(a) == 1)` give a similar result?

Comment: I am certain it will give the same result. I think neither solution is susceptible to errors so it comes down to what suits your taste the most ;)

Answer (score 1):

A solution without dplyr. Work with a flag:

```
# input
df <- data.frame(a = c(1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                 b = c(0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1))

# create new empty df
new_df <- read.table(text = "", col.names = c("a", "b"))
a_okay = FALSE # initialize the flag

for (row_number in seq(1:nrow(df))) { # loop over each row of the original df
  # if a is 1, we add the row to the new df and set the flag to TRUE
  if (df[row_number, "a"] == 1) {
    a_okay = TRUE
    new_df[nrow(new_df) + 1, ] = c(df[row_number, "a"], df[row_number, "b"])
  }
  
  # now we consider the rows where a is not 1
  else {
    # if b is 1 and we are still following an a == 1: add the row
    if (df[row_number, "b"] == 1 & a_okay) {
      new_df[nrow(new_df) + 1, ] = c(df[row_number, "a"], df[row_number, "b"])
    }
    # if b is 0, we reset the flag
    else {
      a_okay = FALSE
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another `base` solution inspired by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49671002/5456906), @Wietse de Vries's answer and @Ben's comment.

```
# input
df <- data.frame(a = c(1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                 b = c(0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1))

# identify groups
df$grp <- cumsum(df$a == 1 | df$b == 0) 

# subset df by groups with first element of a == 1
df <- do.call(rbind, split(df, df$grp)[by(df, df$grp, function(x) {x$a[1] == 1})])

# remove grp
df$grp <- NULL
```